# Slow Full Text When using multiple full text searches

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Thank you in advance for your help.   I have been going bonkers.

We recently made a change to our code by adding an additional contains to the below query.  This has had a real negative impact on performance.  When we remove contains or the other, the query returns right away.

```
select * 
from dbo.company p with (nolock) 
  join dbo.alt_company o  with (nolock) on p.org_id = o.org_id 
where CONTAINS (p.description, '"phrase1*" OR "phrase2"')  
  or  CONTAINS (o.description, '"phrase1*" OR "phrase2"')
```

Why would having the second contains create such havoc on the performance.   The problem is then made worse by the number of keywords.   I have re-written the query in such a way there is only one contains and it works pretty good.  I just want to make sure I understand what's happening.

Thanks,
Pete

Comment: How many rows are in the additional `o.description` college?

Comment: There are about the same rows (40K) in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common work-around for slow `OR` performance is to separate the parts and `UNION ALL` them back together:

```
select * 
from dbo.company p with (nolock) 
  join dbo.alt_company o  with (nolock) on p.org_id = o.org_id 
where CONTAINS (p.description, '"phrase1*" OR "phrase2"')  

UNION ALL -- note the "ALL", this will prevent a "DISTINCT"

select * 
from dbo.company p with (nolock) 
  join dbo.alt_company o  with (nolock) on p.org_id = o.org_id 
where CONTAINS (o.description, '"phrase1*" OR "phrase2"')
```

You may be able to optimise further by referencing `dbo.company` only once in each part; I'll leave that to you to decide according to your needs and business rules.

Oh, and stop using [`select *`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list) and [`WITH (NOLOCK)`](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: haha!  I only used the select * for the example.    And I'm working on trying to get rid of all of the WITH (NOLOCK) hints.   I can only change so much at a time.  :)